# Dataframe standard deviation

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I need to get the standard deviation of all cells
(Not columns and rows but all the cells)

My dataframe looks like this

[image: dataframe]

Expected answer as the standard deviation = 69.61
(Taken from excel)

Comment: sample std or unadjusted std? Use different ddof argument to std depending on which you want. The excel default `STDEV` should be the same as the pandas default of `.std(ddof=1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
df.stack().std()
```